# Rename multiple files at once using cmd [Windows 10]

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename, windows-10-desktop

I want to rename multiple files using command prompt / batch script (as such cases often arise where I need to rename multiple files)

**from -**
quiz-1.png,
quiz-2.png,
quiz-3.png,
..,
..,
quiz-20.png

**to** 
15-quiz-1.png,
15-quiz-2.png,
...
15-quiz-20.png

I tried:
`ren *.* 15-?*.*`
But this is resulting in renaming files as *"15-z-1.png, 15-z-2.png,...."*

Comment: No idea why you're getting downvoted. You have a clear problem statement with the code you tried, your expected result, and your actual result.

Comment: @SomethingDark Yeah that's odd why someone did that.

Comment: yeah. must have been an accidental click .. gone though now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command prompt.

```
for %G IN (quiz-*.png) do rename %G 15-%G
```

Double the percent symbols if you are using this code in a batch file.

Comment: Quote for safety. `for %G IN (quiz-*.png) do rename "%~G" "15-%~G"`